# Access a device connected in another switch

Tags: routing, vlan, hp, 3-com

I have theses two switches, 3Com 4500 and 3Com 2928.

3Com 4500 - IP: 20.20.X.X ; Mask: 255.255.240.0

3Com 2928 - IP: 192.168.1.X; Mask: 255.255.255.0

There is a printer(20.20.2.1) connected in the switch 3Com 4500. I need to access this printer from the devices on the 3Com 2928. I already tried to make a trunk between the switches, and the same Vlan(Vlan 100) in theses two switches one with interface and another without interface, and enable IP Routing, but doesn't work.

I don't know if this is good practice or not, but i did this way...

I create 2 Vlans in each switches

Switch A:

Vlan 255 - 10.5.0.1; 255.255.255.0

Vlan 100 - 192.168.100.2; 255.255.255.0

Switch B:

Vlan 255 - 10.5.0.2; 255.255.255.0

Vlan 200 - 172.168.200.2; 255.255.255.0

I created these routes:

Switch A:

10.5.0.1 - 255.255.255.0 - 10.5.0.2

172.16.200.2 - 255.255.255.0 - 10.5.0.2

Switch B :

10.5.0.2 - 255.255.255. - 10.5.0.1

192.168.100.2 - 255.255.255.0 - 10.5.0.1

Now the Switch A can ping i the switch and the vlans of the "B" and "vice versa". But i can't ping from Vlan 1 in any other vlan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create additional VLANs.  All you need to do is trunk the two VLANs between the switches and enable routing between them.  Make sure the default gateways for your printers and other devices is the router interface address for that VLAN.